# Different versions of rpmbuild list different dependencies

Tags: netbeans, rpm, rpmbuild, netbeans-platform, rpm-spec

I am building a netbeans 8.1 platform application for CentOS6 and CentOS7. These OS's host rpmbuild 4.8.0 and 4.11.3 respectively.

On each OS, I can package the application into a ZIP file distribution in the netbeans 8.1 IDE, which is then referenced in my .spec file.

On both OS, the resulting rpm is built fine (by which I mean, an rpm is produced with no errors).

When I install the rpm on CentOS6, it installs fine and the application runs.

When I install the rpm on CentOS7, rpm returns the following error:

```
D: Requires: osgi(org.tmatesoft.sqljet)            NO
```

(In fact I get a bunch of osgi references, but all the others have satisfied dependencies).

If I list the rpm dependencies with

```
rpm -qpR package.rpm
```

I get the same list of dependencies on both OS, except that on CentOS7 it finds a bunch of osgi() dependencies - these are not present on CentOS6.

Since the only difference between these two proceedures is the version of rpmbuild I am using, I suspect that this is the problem. However, I'm not sure how best to resolve the problem on CentOS7 - I've tried using --nodeps in the rpmbuild command and I've tried adding module dependencies to the project in netbeans, but to no avail. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Install the rpms that provides `osgi`, May be in Centos7 the packaging might have changed.